# How to create shopping list from back-office of Orocommerce

Tags: api, orocrm, orocommerce

[Shopping List](https://doc.oroinc.com/4.1/user/back-office/sales/shopping-lists/) describes that Via the back-office, you can access any shopping list created and saved by the customers in the OroCommerce storefront.

Can we also create a shopping list from Back-office using any of the api's from http://ip-address/admin/api/doc. I see some of the shopping list api's are deprecated.
http://ip-address/admin/api/doc/default#options--api-rest-{version}-shopping-list.{_format}

Answer (score 0):

OOTB Shopping list entity is not enabled in Backoffice API. All enabled resources you can find in API Sandbox. "~/backend-prefix/api/doc" as for Backoffice and "~/api/doc" for Storefront.

"~/backend-prefix/api/doc/default" resource (from your example) it is an old, deprecated plain API implementation and should not be used.

In case you need to add SL via Backoffice API you could "Enable Custom API":
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/api/how-to/#id2